# Why is my destructor never called?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

A CustomPropertyList class is created in my form constructor.

```
form(String ^s)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CustomPropertyList ^propertyList = gcnew CustomPropertyList(s);
...
```

The CustomPropertyList class has a destructor

```
CustomPropertyList::~CustomPropertyList()
{

    if (MessageBox::Show("Do you want to save your changes?","Editin",MessageBoxButtons::YesNo)==DialogResult::Yes)
...
```

Why is it not called when the program exits? (I know it's not as I don't see the message box and there's a breakpoint there)

I'm very grateful for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because this is not destructor, this is Dispose method (in C# terms). If client doesn't call Dispose, it is never called. On the other hand, finalizer (!CustomPropertyList) should be called, unless GC::SuppressFinalize is used to prevent it.

From C# code, ~CustomPropertyList can be called by using Dispose. From C++/CLI client code, it can be called by using delete operator.

See more details in this C++/CLI guru article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppclidtors.aspx

Answer (score 2):

From .net, a C++/CLI class looks like a class that implements the `IDisposable` interface. To invoke the destructor, you'll have to call `Dispose` on the object.

Answer (score 1):

In C++/CLI, if you want objects to have lifetime controlled by the enclosing scope (for member subobjects, the same lifetime as the parent), declare them without the handle or pointer syntax.

e.g.

```
CustomPropertyList propertyList(s);
```

or for a member subobject:

```
ref class form
{
    CustomPropertyList propertyList;
    form(String^ s)
      : propertyList(s)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```